# (Pugh) Describe set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at distance exactly $1/2$ from the unit circle $S^1$ in the plane

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The following problem is taken from [Real Mathematical Analysis](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319177700) by Pugh, page $125,$ exercise $3.$

> What is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at distance exactly $1/2$ from the unit circle $S^1$ in the plane,
>       $$T= \{ p \in \mathbb{R}^3: \exists q \in S^1 \text{ and } d(p,q) = 1/2 \text{ and for all }q^{\prime} \in S^1 \text{ we have } d(p,q) \leq d(p,q^{\prime})\}?$$

If we fix $q\in S^1,$ then $T_q$ is a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $q.$
Since we want to collect all $q\in S^1,$ so I think the set $T$ is actually a torus. However, I do not know how to prove it.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show that this set is bijective to $S^1 \times S^1$?

Comment: Hint: use the symmetry of the unit circle $S^1$ to simplify the problem. Then apply in reverse the symmetry to find the complete set of solutions.

Comment: @Martigan: Can you elaborate more on your hint? I do not understand your hint.

Comment: the exercise is not so clear. How is $S^1$ embedded in $\Bbb R^3$? If it is embedded in the plane $XY$ then the figure that you want is a torus.

Answer (score 2):

Further explanation of my hint.

The circle $S^1$ is of course within a plane. Let's suppose it is the plane $z=0$ (but it does not matter anyway).

Then you know that the circle is invariable by rotation of any angle around the axis $(x=0,y=0)$.

Look at the plane $x=0$ and what does the circle $S^1$ becomes in this plane, and where, in that plane, are the set of points that respects your hypothesis.

Then extend back to the whole space.

Comment: Sorry. I still do not understand your hint. I see it possible for you to write up full solution?

Answer (score 1):

$$ S = \{ x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x^{2} + y^{2} = 1 \} $$
$$ T = \{ p \in \mathbb{R}^{3}, q \in S \mid d(p,q) = 1/2 \} $$

Yes, it's a Torus.